# Duty officers with resolve

Tags: star-trek-online

When looking through engineering assignments, they often require officers with **resolve**, though I cant seem to find any to buy.  There are even some assignments where "Resolve" is listed as the main requirement, where it might say "Geologist" or "Botanist".

What kind of officers have resolve, and where can I acquire them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can buy packs from the C-store that have a random chance to produce personnel with the resolve stat.

It's possible to win these duty personnel buy completing certain random duty missions.

Lastly, if you have the patience, you could check the Exchange; there's no way to search for that particular stat however.

The following duty officer can be obtained at the Academy by exchanging 5 green quality duty officers:

- Name: Voloror
- Race: Vulcan (Female)
- Rank: Lt. Junior
- Dept: Security
- Specialization: Security Officer Ground
- Traits: Tactful, FF, Logical, Resolve, Telepathic

Answer (score 0):

The [StarTrek Online Wiki](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Trait:_Resolve/doff#Available_resolve_duty_officers) has an extensive list of duty officers with the Resolve trait.

As you can see, almost all officers with this trait are of purple quality, so they are not easy to come by. A lot of them are random drops from drop boxes, from a duty officer pack and events.

Officers that are rewards for assignment chains or missions:

Federation:

- [Elizabeth Mohr](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Elizabeth_Mohr)
- [Flight Officer Liow'an](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Flight_Officer_Liow%27an)
- [J'Tenall](http://sto.gamepedia.com/J%27Tenall)

Klingon empire:

- [Hisow Ja'fus Anaun](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Hisow_Ja%27fus_Anaun)
- [J'Tynsen](http://sto.gamepedia.com/J%27Tynsen)
- [Mochaak](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Mochaak)

Cross faction:

- [Charol](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Charol)
- [Gul Tain](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Gul_Tain)
- [Gumarre](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Gumarre)
- [Veol](http://sto.gamepedia.com/Veol)

Take a look at their pages, the notes section contains how they can be obtained.